# Calculated column on SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

I use SharePoint 2013 FDN List for a basic IT Helpdesk - I'm looking to created a calculated column that can measure time it takes for a case to be closed.

Date Created and Status = Not Started

TO

Status = Complete

Any ideas? Or is this even possible, seeing as I don't input a date for when it's completed. Maybe it could work off date last modified?

It will be used to export to excel and run metrics.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have 1 column to store information then another for the calculated value. Using a workflow, you would log the modified date in your first column when the status is set to complete. Then your calculated column would be something like `=[Column1] - [Created]`